# Atlas mongoDB cloud service with dart package mongo_dart cause Connection Exception

Tags: mongodb, dart, mongo-dart

I'm trying to write into Atlas mongoDB cloud service with dart package mongo_dart.

This is how to connect to:

```
  static const String uri =
      "mongodb+srv://User:Password@Project.e0nro.mongodb.net/DbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority&tls=true";

  Future<Db> connectToDatabase() async {
    var db = await Db.create(uri);
    await db.open(secure: true);
    print('Connected to database');
    return db;
  }
```

And this is how to update my data:

```
await coll.update(
            {
              "symbol": symbol,
            },
            {
              r"$addToSet": {"pens": pen.toJson()}
            },
          );
```

I've got this error rapidly:

```
Unhandled exception:
MongoDB ConnectionException: connection closed: The socket connection has been reset by peer.
Possible causes:
- Trying to connect to an ssl/tls encrypted database without specifiyng
  either the query parm tls=true or the secure=true parameter in db.open()
- Others
```

And sometimes this one:

```
Unhandled exception:
MongoDB ConnectionException: connection closed: SocketException: Read failed (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), address = ????.e0nro.mongodb.net, port = 52508
```

In Atlas panel I added the IP address to access the database globally

```
0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)   access  Active
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Try adding `ssl=true&authSource=admin` to your connecting string .

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I've already added but again the error cause my app stopped

Comment: Unhandled exception:
MongoDB ConnectionException: connection closed: SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = dbname-shard-00-01.e0nro.mongodb.net, port = 55472

Comment: Are you able to connect to MongoDB compass or mongo shell?

Comment: Yes I can connect with these code for a while but it happens after  10 min more or less

Comment: When you connect with "mongodb+srv://" the `tls=true` parameter is implicit, so you do not need to specify it.

Comment: Which version of mongo_dart are you using? 
So the problem does not happens immediately, you can work for a while and then you get that message? Cannot be a network problem?

Comment: @JF mongo_dart: ^0.5.0+1 Yeah you are right I can work for a while and then I get that message. the network is not problem and I can ping

Comment: I tell you that the network can be a problem, because it happened to me that I had a problem with my wi-fi router. Periodically it stopped the connection for a couple of minutes. After that my connection to the database was always down, and I had to reconnect.

Comment: @JF I don't really know because I'm new and it is on VPS with ubuntu as OS

Comment: You can only mange these cases testing db.isConnected. If not, before any operation is better to get a new Db element ( I do not remind if it is enough to re-call db.open()...).

Comment: I have the same problem.
Did you solve these errors?